# How to update multiple compressed files with 7zip command line?

Tags: command-line, compression, 7-zip

I need to update the file "background.png" into hundreds of .zip files in the same directory. I tried the following command without success:

```
7z u -r "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testzip\*.zip" "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testzip\background.png"
```

I get the error "cannot open file".
Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and don't worry, I will keep up until this is finished. The only issue is that I am in a different time zone, also I am not very familiar with the etiquette in superuser and it looks like I still need to earn some privileges like flagging another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add one specific file to every zip file recursively with 7-Zip

Use a [For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop and the  [Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command using the `/S /B /A-D` switches to iterate over each zip file one by one recursively from the starting directory down and update each archive file this way.

**Note:** *With this method you will omit and not use the [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) `-r` switch with the update parameter.*

---

### Command Line

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %A in ('DIR /S /B /A-D "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testzip\*.zip"') DO 7z u "%~fA" "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testzip\background.png"
```

---

### Batch Script

**Note:** *You can set the value of the `SET Src=` variable to be that of the full path starting folder you wish to update zip files within recursively. You can set the `SET uFile=` variable value to be the full path of the file you are updating the zip files with; the update file.*

```
@ECHO ON

SET Src=C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testzip
SET uFile=C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testzip\background.png

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A in ('DIR /S /B /A-D "%Src%\*.zip"') DO (
    7z u "%%~fA" "%uFile%"
)
```

---

### Further Resources

- [For /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- **`FOR /?`**

  > ```
  >     tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
  >                       be passed to the for body for each iteration.
  >                       This will cause additional variable names to
  >                       be allocated.  The m-n form is a range,
  >                       specifying the mth through the nth tokens.  If
  >                       the last character in the tokens= string is an
  >                       asterisk, then an additional variable is
  >                       allocated and receives the remaining text on
  >                       the line after the last token parsed.
  > ```
  >
  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
  > ```
- [Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [-u (Update options) switch](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/update.htm)

Comment: Why is echo ON?

Comment: Personal preference... and because I'm cool!!! LOL

Comment: Thanks a lot for the script. I run some tests and it doesn't update the content of the zip files and the batch closes to fast to see the result. Is there a way to prevent the command window to close? By the way, the zip files do not contain any folders/subfolders, only files.

Comment: update:I run some extra tests and I noticed that in fact the batch is adding the background.png to the zip files but not updating them if it already exists.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I have the same version 7-zip 18.01 (x64). I am running the batch as an admin from the 7zip folder and I get the following result:

Updating archive: C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testzip\archive 1.zip

Keep old data in archive: 1 folder, 3 files, 39664 bytes (39 KiB)
Add new data to archive: 0 files, 0 bytes


Files read from disk: 0
Archive size: 12324 bytes (13 KiB)
Everything is Ok

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I re-copy/pasted your batch script code just to be sure but I get the same result if I run it normally or as an admin. `@ECHO ON

SET Src=C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testzip
SET uFile=C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testzip\background.png

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A in ('DIR /S /B /A-D "%Src%\*.zip"') DO (
    7z u "%%~fA" "%uFile%"
)`

Comment: I have run a new test in a different machine with different files and I realized that in some cases the file I was trying to update in the zip was newer so they were skipped. After creating a new version of background.pgn the process run correctly in most of them. However, I still have some zips that still cannot be updated and I can't figure out the reason. In this dropbox folder I have included both pgn files, a sample zip and the error message I get. Please let me know if you need any more info. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pzdalnbyda8027s/AACMqTwpui1BkQz-d9NSlp2Sa?dl=0)

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I am at CEST. I have redone the test with newly created files and now it is working. I think some of the zip files were corrupted but now the process finishes perfectly. Thanks a lot!